# EF Core does not update Entity property generated by DB after insert operation when DTO manually mapped to Entity class

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am running in the following problem. I have a RandomDTO and a RandomEntity. When I project a collection of RandomDTOs to collection of RandomEntities using LINQ and then insert it to DB the property on RandomEntity which should be generated by DB is not updated on the RandomEntity after insert operation. This only happens when DTO collection is manually projected to Entity collection. No issues when using Automapper.

Examples:

```
public class RandomDTO
{
  public int PropertyA { get; set; }
  public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}

public class RandomEntity
{
  public int Id {get;set;}
  public int PropertyA { get; set; } // This is a default value generated by db
  public string PropertyB { get; set; }
}


public class SomeContext : DbContext
{
  // ...some context implementation... 

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
  {
    modelBuilder.HasSequence<int>("MySequence", "dbo").StartsAt(1).IncrementsBy(1);
    modelBuilder.Entity<RandomEntity>().Property(o => o.PropertyA).HasDefaultValueSql("NEXT VALUE FOR dbo.MySequence");
  }
}


public class RandomRepo
{
  //...some repo implementation...

  public async Task<IEnumerable<RandomEntity>> AddEntities(IEnumerable<RandomEntity> randomEntities)
  {
    foreach (var ent in randomEntities)
    {
      await _ctx.RandomEntities.AddAsync(ent);
    }


    await _ctx.SaveChangesAsync();


    return randomEntities.ToList(); 
  }
}


//...implemetation of a calling class is omitted for simplicity....

public class CallingMethod()
{
  // Collection of randomDTOs
  IEnumerable<RandomDTO> randomDTOs =  [...some collections of random dtos...];


  //Manual projection
  var randomEntitiesManual = randomDTOs.Select(dto => new RandomEntity()
  {
    PropertyA = dto.PropertyA,
    PropertyB = dto.PropertyB
  });


  // Mapping with automapper
  var randomEntitiesAuto = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<RandomEntity>>(randomDTOs);


  var resultManual = _randomRepo.AddEntities(randomEntitiesManual); // with manual projection PropertyA = 0 fore every entity in collection 

  var resultAuto = _randomRepo.AddEntities(randomEntitiesAuto ); //with Automapper PropertyA = VALUE generated by DB for every entity in collection
}
```

Could someone explain why does it happen? And how to implement manual mapping when working with EF Core?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to experience this situation, I think you defined the problem wrongly. Auto Mapper is do not perform logical operations, they simply assign data.

1. Compare and debug data from 2 models.
2. Check your entities and be sure.
3. Make sure the id column is correct.